# add exception handling as jar in spring boot, controller advice is not getting called

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am trying to remove exception handling from the service and trying to add it as dependency. I had build the application and added that as dependency, I am able to see all the classes in that. for custom exception handling I am binding data to class that is in the exception (which is added as jar ) that extends the Runtime Exception but its calling the controller advice class, its returning the error directly to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue, I need to scan the error handler application in the other application with the baseScanPackages({give package name of error handler that needs to be added here}) or needs to create an annotation for the error handler application